# replace thousands separators in csv with regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm running into problems trying to pull the thousands separators out of some currency values in a set of files. The "bad" values are delimited with commas and double quotes. There are other values in there that are < $1000 that present no issue.

Example of existing file:

```
"12,345.67",12.34,"123,456.78",1.00,"123,456,789.12"
```

Example of *desired* file (thousands separators removed):

```
"12345.67",12.34,"123456.78",1.00,"123456789.12"
```

I found a regex expression for matching the numbers with separators that works great, but I'm having trouble with the -replace operator. The replacement value is confusing me. I read about $& and I'm wondering if I should use that here. I tried $_, but that pulls out ALL my commas. Do I have to use $matches somehow?

Here's my code:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem *input.csv
foreach ($file in $Files)
    {
        $file |
        Get-Content | #assume that I can't use -raw
        % {$_ -replace '"[\d]{1,3}(,[\d]{3})*(\.[\d]+)?"', ("$&" -replace ',','')} | #this is my problem
        out-file output.csv -append -encoding ascii
    }
```

Comment: Use import-csv and then you can loop through the rows and items, remove the commas from each item, while building new rows as you go along, then save the new rows to the file overwriting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with this regex:

```
,(?=(\d{3},?)+(?:\.\d{1,3})?")
```

See [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pP9cW8/1) or in powershell:

```
% {$_ -replace ',(?=(\d{3},?)+(?:\.\d{1,3})?")','' }
```

---

But it's more about the challenge that regex can bring. For proper work, use @briantist answer which is the clean way to do this.

Comment: This worked like a CHAMP and has prodded me to read more about things like "positive assertions" and "lookahead groups". Thanks Thomas.

Answer (score 5):

Tony Hinkle's comment is the answer: don't use regex for this (at least not directly on the CSV file).

Your CSV is valid, so you should parse it as such, work on the objects (change the text if you want), then write a new CSV.

```
Import-Csv -Path .\my.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace ',',''
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path .\my_new.csv
```

(this code needs work, specifically the middle as the row will have each column as a property, not an array, but a more complete version of your CSV would make that easier to demonstrate)

Answer (score 3):

I would use a simpler regex, and use capture groups instead of the entire capture.
I have tested the follow regular expression with your input and found no issues.

`% {$_ -replace '([\d]),([\d])','$1$2' }`

eg. Find all commas with a number before and after (so that the weird mixed splits dont matter) and replace the comma entirely.

This would have problems if your input has a scenario without that odd mixing of quotes and no quotes.

Comment: Personally, I love this answer. You can straight up import the file as text, run the regex replace, and output it as text. No need to convert things to objects, so it should cut down on overhead. You could even make it a lookahead/lookbehind and skip the last part of the replace. [RegEx101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/nL2rM9/2)

Comment: This is great, too. I thought it would fail with multiple separators (e.g. 123,456,789.12) but it works and now I see why.

Comment: I'm so grateful to ConstantineK for the answer, and TheMadTechnician for the RedEx link!  I converted all my numbers by using the online tester!